# Java: Forward declarations of classes in namespaces

Tags: java, forward-declaration

How do I do forward declarations in Java?

I have two classes, each needs to call a method in the other and they both reside within different namespaces. For example...

```
package one;

class A {
    public void foo() {
        B b = new B();
        b.bah();
    }
}
```

and

```
package two;

class B {
    public void bah() {
        A a = new A();
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

UPDATE

In Eclipse when this code is encountered a compile time error would be thrown up "A cycle was detected in the build path...".

Comment: I assume this is just an example you are giving and you are aware that it will cause a StackOverflowError?

Comment: Also note that this is generally an indication that you've got some problems in your design. Dependencies should generally be in one direction only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import them.  Java is a lot cleverer than C++ about these things.

Comment: The order of imports is not important in Java. Cyclic references are possible without any extra code.

Answer (score 1):

> In Eclipse when this code is encountered a compile time error would be thrown up "A cycle was detected in the build path...".

I think that Eclipse is complaining because you have a circular dependency between classes in different Eclipse projects in your workspace.  Eclipse wants to be able to build projects in a linear sequence.

If you put the mutually dependent classes into the same project, Eclipse would be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you import the classes:

```
package one;

import two.B;

class A {
    public void foo() {
        new B().bah();
    }
}
```

or use their full name:

```
package one;

class A {
    public void foo() {
        new two.B().bah();
    }
}
```

But, needless to say, that will cause an exception to be thrown (at least, in the snippet you posted...).

Comment: @Ben, yeah, I thought you knew, but wanted to mention it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Given the comments here (ie you don't need to do explicit forward declarations as the compiler can cope) I have downgraded the Eclipse error to a warning and will have to just ignore it.

To do this go to...

Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Building > Build path problems > Circular dependences

Comment: Surely Eclipse is warning you that you will get a StackOverflowError if you run this code? Or does your real code have some sort of break out condition that will stop the continuous cycle?

Comment: this isn't 'real code', it's just an example of some code that describes my problem.